# How to redirect after submitting form in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to redirect same form page after submitting form with alert box. how i can set please help on this.. thank you so much

PHP CODE HERE

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'test@website.web.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n"."contact number: $contact.\n".
    "Here is the message: $message.\n"."Email ID: $visitor_email.\n".

$to = "lead@lead.web.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done.
printf("<script> alert('Thank You!'); </script>");

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

in this code i am only getting alert box i want to redirect same page after submitting form. please help on this

MY HTML IS

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP form to email sample form</title>
<!-- define some style elements-->
<style>
label,a 
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px; 
}

</style>    
<!-- a helper script for vaidating the form-->
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>

<!-- Start code for the form-->
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Enter Name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='email'>Enter Email Address:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </p>
    <p> 
            <label for='contact'>Contact Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='message'>Enter Message:</label> <br>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
// Code for validating the form
// Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
// for details
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myemailform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in the begginning of your php code:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: i want to get thanks alert too...

Comment: @Kallu Then you put the script in the page to which you are redirecting. PS: Do not forget to accept this answer by clicking the check mark on the left if this helped :)